# Getting S shape with Bezier curve on canvas in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have this code to draw a Bezier curve:

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(20, 20);
ctx.bezierCurveTo(30, 100, 200, 100, 200, 200);
ctx.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="400" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
```

This code results in a S shaped Beizer curve:
[image]

My problem is that I want to change the start and end control points as per my wish but at the same time I want that S shape to be there.

I have observed whenever I change the control points, the overall shape of the curve becomes strange.

What is the way out?

Comment: That is quite vague: please share the code which does not output what you desire, and draw what you had expected instead. Also, please use Stack Snippet to have a runnable demo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the S shape is currently displayed as you wish, then the middle control points are such that their X-coordinate roughly matches the X-coordinate of the end point they are closest to, and the Y-coordinate is the same for both middle control points: it is about half-way the Y range of the end points.

So you can calculate the control points dynamically if you only have the two end points:

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

function drawS(start, end) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(...start);
    let midY = (start[1] + end[1]) / 2;
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(start[0], midY, end[0], midY, ...end);
    ctx.stroke();
}

drawS([20, 20], [200, 180]);
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="200" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas>
```